# Most efficient way to get an array of every minute in a given day?

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar

I'm trying to build an array of `[Date]` that represents every minute in a given day.  This is what I've come up with but wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve this?

```
let calendar = Calendar.current

var arrayOfDaysMinutes: [Date] = []

var midnight = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())

if let endOfDayDate = calendar.date(bySettingHour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59, of: midnight) {
    print("midnight = \(midnight) and one second before midnight = \(endOfDayDate)")
    
    for i in 0...1440 {
        print("i = \(i)")
        let nextMinute = midnight.addingTimeInterval(60 * Double(i))
        arrayOfDaysMinutes.append(nextMinute)
    }
    
    print("arrayOfDaysMinutes count = \(arrayOfDaysMinutes.count)")
    
    for minute in arrayOfDaysMinutes {
        print("minute = \(minute)")
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that not every day has 24 hours. It might have 23 or 25 as well. Regarding most efficient way I think that using DateComponentes date property works much faster than adding minutes or getting the next date after a date:

---

```
extension Date {
    func year(using calendar: Calendar = .current) ->  Int {
        calendar.component(.year, from: self)
    }
    func month(using calendar: Calendar = .current) ->  Int {
        calendar.component(.month, from: self)
    }
    func day(using calendar: Calendar = .current) ->  Int {
        calendar.component(.day, from: self)
    }
    func noon(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Date  {
        calendar.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)!
    }
    func startOfDay(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Date {
        calendar.startOfDay(for: self)
    }
    func dayAfter(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Date {
        calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: noon(using: calendar))!
    }
    func startOfNextDay(using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> Date {
        calendar.startOfDay(for: dayAfter(using: calendar))
    }
}
```

---

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let date = Date()
let startOfDay = date.startOfDay(using: calendar)
let startOfNextDay = startOfDay.startOfNextDay(using: calendar)
let minutes = calendar.dateComponents([.minute], from: startOfDay, to: startOfNextDay).minute!
let year = date.year(using: calendar)
let month = date.month(using: calendar)
let day = date.day(using: calendar)

let dates = (0..<minutes).compactMap {
    DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: year, month: month, day: day, minute: $0).date
}
print("minutes count:", dates.count)  // "minutes count: 1440\n"

for minute in dates {
    print("minute = \(minute)")
}
```

Comment: When you say every day doesn't necessarily have 24 hours are you referring to day light savings time in the US?

Comment: Yes it can be any locale which adopts daylight savings time. Btw Brazil used to have it but 2 years ago they dropped dlst